# Android how to show toolbar after hiding (by scrolling down in RecyclerView)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-toolbar, bottomnavigationview

I have *BottomNavigationView* with three fragments. First one has a *RecyclerView* and I implemented to hide Toolbar after scrolling this RecyclerView and it works. When I change fragment I would like to show it again (actionbar) - but actionbar.isShowing() returns true and actionbar.show() doesn't work. Maybe somebody has an idea?

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@android:color/white"
     tools:context=".main.MainActivity">

<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/mainToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
        app:title="@string/app_name"/>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/mainNav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"
    app:menu="@menu/user_tabs_menu" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Create one method to gone/visible mainToolbar in activity.
Now for each fragment in onAttach() make visibility gone & onDeatch() make visibility visible. 

So when any fragment get attach then visibility become gone and when you backpress  then fragment get detach and toolbar become visible.

So use as per your requirements

Comment: @KishanMaurya he is trying to make CoordinatorLayout work, there is no need to mess with actual visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change fragments you should call [AppBarLayout.setExpanded(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/appbar/AppBarLayout.html#setexpanded_1)

Comment: That works. Thank you. But can I do it without animation?

Comment: @Oktawian yes, there's an overloaded method [setExpanded(boolean expanded, boolean animate)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/appbar/AppBarLayout.html#setexpanded), you should just add false, like this `setExpanded(true, false)`

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us some code on how are you making the toolbar disappear?